# The use of "tu" in Spanish

Tags: traducción, gramática, pronombres

As 'tu' in Spanish means both "his/her" and "your", the following sentence:

> Ella es tu única hermana.

Can the sentence be translated both as:

> She is your only sister.

and

> She is his only sister.

Comment: Just mention that única has graphic accent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Tu** means two things in Spanish: **you**, **of yours** or simply **your**. In other words **tu** is both, a personal pronoun (in the form of **Tú**) as well as the possessive pronoun (in the form of **Tu**).

The sentence "Ella es **tu** unica hermana" can only be translated as:

> She is **your** only sister.

If you would like to say "She is **his** only sister" you would need to say:

> Ella es **su** unica hermana.

If you would like to say "She is **her** only sister" you would need to follow the example above since Spanish does not have a separate gender for the possessive pronouns of his or hers as it is done in English.

Comment: Tu doesn't mean you. That's tú. That accent actually does change pronunciation.

Comment: @Deningrad you should edit your answer in order to express the difference between **tú** and **tu**. It is very important for people who are learning Spanish.

Comment: True, sorry for that. Tú and Tu have been now differentiated.

Comment: No, you are still saying at the beginning that *tu* has two meanings. It doesn't.